# Cannot import seaborn in ipython but works fine in python console

Tags: python, import, ipython, seaborn

I have this wired problem on company issued windows 7 laptop.

install python 3.5 (anaconda), and other packages with conda. But I have a problem:

I cannot use seaborn in Jupyter (Ipython) notebook.

Checked if seaborn is properly installed by conda:

```
>conda list
...
seaborn                   0.7.0                    py35_0
...
```

sure enough seaborn 0.7.0 is listed

run python in terminal and import seaborn, it worked fine:

```
[py3] >python
Python 3.5.1 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| ...
>>> import seaborn
>>>
```

run ipython in terminal, but I cannot import seaborn:

```
[py3] >ipython
Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| .... 
In [1]: import seaborn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-085c0287ecb5> in <module>()
----> 1 import seaborn

ImportError: No module named 'seaborn'
```

I have remove and then installed scipy, numpy, seaborn. But still no luck.

Any hint?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you install `ipython` in same virtualenv as seaborn install. Normally IPython sits in the default path and can be called even in virtualenvs it doesn't installed on them.

Comment: You are correct about the virtualenv. I was under false impression that anaconda makes it base installation transparent to virtualenv. installing ipython in the same env fixed issue importing seaborn in ipython console; installing notebook in the same env fixed importing issue in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: I removed `ipython` from my system and installed it only on the environment I needed it. Now I can import `seaborn` from `ipython` with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error, and I can confirm that it has nothing to do with having the wrong virtualenv. If I import `seaborn` from the ipython console, it imports without error; if I do the same from the notebook, the module cannot be found. I have confirmed that the notebook is running from the virtualenv.